# How to get a STANDARD lightning component into visualforce (or another lightning component)

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am looking for a way to get one of the standard lightning components into my own component.

I want to do the same thing as I do with custom components like:
       `<c:myComponent />`

To be specific I want the activity standard component so it would be something like:

```
<SFNamespace:Activity />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that if the component is actually exposed to the public.  On your org go to .lightning.force.com/auradocs/reference.app

and you will see a list of components that you can use (including the one made available by SF).

Specifically there should be:
force/forceChatter/forceCommunity/lightning/ui - those are SF components

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can actually do this but not via markup though (tested in Summer 17).
In your component's markup, define a container component, e.g.

```
<div aura:id="componentContainer"></div>
```

Then in you controller or helper you can load the activity timeline component like this:

`createActivityTimeline: function (component, event, helper)
    {
        var container = component.find("containerTest");
        $A.createComponent("runtime_sales_activities:activityPanel",
                {
                    recordId: component.get('v.recordId')
                },
                function(cmp) {
                    container.set("v.body", [cmp]);
                });
    }`

Notice the name of the component *runtime_sales_activities:activityPanel*.
As said at the beginning, it won't work through markup though.

Comment: Hi Christoph. Where did you get the component name from? Can this be found somewhere in documentation?