# Standard component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visualforce-component, standard-objects

Can we extend a class in Standard Component?
or
Can we get the code of a Standard Component?

If No, then please provide a link where salesforce says that we cannot customise a standard Component.

My main aim is to customize a STANDARD COMPONENT.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! I think you'll find the community here more responsive if you go into detail about what it is you're trying to accomplish. Right now, this sounds like an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Extending/customizing a standard component is the solution (the "Y") that you've settled on, but what is the "X" (the problem/goal you're trying to solve/achieve)? Customizing a component may not be the best solution here. Also, are you working with Lightning, or Visualforce (or Visualforce in Lightning)? Your tags make it unclear what exactly you're working with.

Comment: I thought this might be useful to to look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154883/how-to-get-a-standard-lightning-component-into-visualforce-or-another-lightning

Answer (score 3):

No, we cannot extend a standard component and I don't have any document which says this. But here is an idea for which you can vote.

[Source code to standard Lightning Components](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003UW8QAM)

Comment: Agreed, but i was looking for a strong proof which says so. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with Salesforce documentation is it often does not state what "can't" be done, instead focusing on what "can" be done. As such, the *lack* of documentation stating that you *can* extend standard components is proof that you *can't*. You can, however, get the source code for the Aura components in the [Aura source code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/). Basically, you can see the source for all components that start with `aura:`, but not `force:`, `lightning:`, etc.